# Use of present tense in a subordinate clause within a sentence that uses future tense

Tags: tenses, subordinate-clauses, sequence-of-tenses

Is the use of tenses correct in the following sentence ?

"One of the key components will be the XXX that replaces the existing YYY."

In particular, the use of the present tense in the subordinate clause whereas the main clause uses the future. It seems correct to me because the present expresses something that is true already now.

Comment: People are still being taught that there are rules against using several different tenses in the same sentence. For the record, there are no such rules. It doesn't matter if they're in the same sentence, and you usually get a choice of tenses when there are two events mentioned. Stop worrying about tenses; native English speakers pay no attention to their use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.

*The XXX that replaces the existing YYY* is a noun phrase. You can consider it as a black box being placed into the surrounding sentence.

> One of the key components will be *[something]*.

---

Consider an actual sentence rather than just the variables:

> One of the fruits on display will be **the Gala apple**.

You can add adjectival information to the noun:

> One of the fruits on display will be **the Gala apple** *[that won first prize at the harvest competition]*.

---

Returning to your original sentence:

> One of the key components will be ***XXX*** *[that replaces the existing YYY]*.

The only thing that makes this look strange is the use of the variables. Here is a more exact sentence that uses an actual example:

> One of the new technologies on display will be **the Wonder Car** *[that replaces the existing types of gasoline with white bread for its fuel]*.